# Siebel Business(E-script) Service Calculate Expiry Date

Tags: scripting, siebel

I have a requirement to create a business service function to calculate expiry date , 2 weeks from a date field in Siebel.

I have written the code in Java which is

```
public static Date checkexpiry(Date Datefield)
    {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(Datefield);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -14);
    Date twoWeeksToExpiry = cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(twoWeeksToExpiry);
        return twoWeeksToExpiry;
    }

if current date is equal to twoWeeksToExpiry {do .....}
```

So how can I re-write this code on Siebel using a business service particularly E-script.

The whole idea is have an output Yes is its 2 weeks before a date field in Siebel.

This will later be used in a work flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so have started Migrating my Java coding skills to Siebel E-Script I came up with this.

```
function ExpiryNotification(Inputs,Outputs)
{
    try
    {
            var expiryDate = Inputs.GetProperty("DateField");
            var eDate= new Date(expiryDate);
            var notificationdate = eDate-14;
            var currentdate = Today();

            if (currentdate==notificationdate){

            Outputs.SetProperty("Notification", "Y")

            }

            else {
             Outputs.SetProperty("Notification", "N")
            }

    catch(e)
    {
        TheApplication().RaiseErrorText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

However I did not use the Business Service ..I used a calculated field on my Business Component.
The calculated Fields

1  twoWeeksToExpiry = Datefield-14

2. Notification = IIf (Today()==[twoWeeksToExpiry], "Y", "N")

So this solved the problem without scripting,

Will appreciate any suggestions on my scripting thou I didn't use it.